# Ruby on Rails - Most Efficient Way to Compare Two Large Arrays for non-matching results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-2

I have some legacy code in my app that compares all table rows for a model with the result of an API call from a supplier.

This worked fine until last week where both the number of table rows and the number of results by the supplier increased massively.

The table cardinality has went from 1,657 to 59,699 and the number of results returned by the API is ~ 150,000.

What the code is doing is looking in the API results to check that if the current table row data is not found, if so then the current data is orphaned in the database since it exists there but not in what the supplier has given us.

Looking through 150,000 results to check if something **isn't** there doesn't sound particularly clever to me and that looks to be the case as I don't even know how long this takes to run as the view is still loading after about half an hour :/

**Controller**

```
@telco_numbers = TelcoNumber.orphaned_in_db
```

**Model**

```
def self.orphaned_in_db
  db_numbers = self.find(:all)
  listed_numbers = self.all_telco
  orphaned_numbers = []
  db_numbers.each do |db|
    scan = listed_numbers.select{ |l| l.number == db.number}
    orphaned_numbers.push(db) if scan.empty?
  end
  return orphaned_numbers
end

def self.some_telco(per_page, page = 1)
  page = 1 if page.nil?
  # this is the first api call which returns a link which is then used for the next api call
  api_call = TelcoApiv3.new("post", "/numbers/#{TelcoApiv3.account_id}/allocated/all")
  listed_numbers = TelcoApiv3.poll(api_call.response["link"])
  return listed_numbers.collect do |ln| 
    ln.store("countrycode", ln["country_code"])
    TelcoNumber.new ln
  end
end

def self.all_telco(page = 1)
  listed_numbers = some_telco(@@max_nlist_results, page)
  if listed_numbers.length == @@max_nlist_results
    return listed_numbers.concat(all_telco(page + 1))
  else
    return listed_numbers
  end
end
```

Example API result format:

```
[{"country_code":"44","number":"1133508889"},....
```

The `number` relates to the `number` column in the table for the model. (It is stored as a varchar and not as a number).

Also, the api results are returned in ascending number order so are already sorted so I would have thought that would have made things better than they are?

Comment: You are looking for numbers that not belong to a telco, if I read it correctly. What we do not see is how you do decide to which `Telco` a `TelcoNumber` belongs. I would write a direct query on the database to find the orphaned numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not trying Array difference. First make two arrays of db_numbers & listed_numbers and subtract the smaller array from the bigger one like this:

```
def self.orphaned_in_db
  db_numbers = self.find(:all).map{|x| x.number}
  listed_numbers = self.all_telco.map{|x| x.number}
  orphaned_numbers = db_numbers - listed_numbers
  orphaned_results = self.find(orphaned_numbers)
  return orphaned_results
end
```

When I will subtract the listed_numbers from db_numbers, I will get the non-matching results set. and now you can find the results on the basis of orphaned_numbers in your database. It will be much faster. Thanks

Comment: Still the problem remains you are first retrieving all numbers from the database, and then all telco numbers from the database. It would be more efficient, if possible, to directly only retrieve the orphaned numbers from the database.

Comment: I think that problem doesn't exist in querying 150k results. But the problem is in his code, that he is looping through 150k numbers one by one and comparing each number with listed numbers, that will be minimum 50k, I assume. So he is running loop (150k x 50k) It is making process slower.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, will give it a try. Also, the 150k isn't from my own database, it's from an external API call otherwise a query would be quite straight forward.

Comment: good news is that your code seems to be quite a big improvement but I get an error saying that `Couldn't find all TelcoNumbers with IDs (...)` so would it be best to do `find_all_by_id` instead so that it returns `null` instead of an error? If I make that change I then get `A JSON text must at least contain two octets!` which was an error I was experiencing before when trying to tackle this problem.

Comment: hmm, just tried again and it ran fine (no JSON error), strange, that should hopefully be it resolved now, thanks again @RailsGuy